# Error retrieving the summary from clogit model

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, spline, survival-analysis

I am training a Conditional logistic regression model with `clogit` on multiple datasets (with thousands of events) in the following way:

```
library(survival) 
library(mgcv)

# load dataset 
df <- read.csv('1.csv')

model <- clogit(case ~ 
           var1 +
           # pspline(var2, df = 3) +
           strata(var3),
           data = df)

print(model)
summary(model)
```

The column types are: case: int, var1: factor, var2: int, var3: int.

If I keep this line commented: `pspline(var2, df = 3) +`, the summary printing works fine when the dataset has enough cases in each strata, otherwise I get the following warning and very large standard errors:

```
Warning message in fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights, :
“Loglik converged before variable  1,2,3 ; beta may be infinite. ”
```

However, if I use the line `pspline(var2, df = 3) +`, then I do not get such warnings even when the dataset does not have enough cases in each strata. The `print(model)` line works, but I get the following error when I try to access the `summary` of the model:

```
Error in pchisq(cox$score, df, lower.tail = FALSE): Non-numeric argument to mathematical function
Traceback:

1. print(summary(model))
2. summary(model)
3. summary.coxph(model)
4. pchisq(cox$score, df, lower.tail = FALSE)
```

I need to access the summary because I am printing the coefficients to a csv file for later processing: `summary(model)$coefficients` since I am training the models on multiple files.

I could not find a reason for this behavior, and any help would be appreciated.

---

Edit: 06.26
**Minimum reproducible example:**

```
num_cases = 100
var3 = rep((1:num_cases), each=3)
case = rep(c(0, 1, 1), num_cases)
var1 = factor(sample(c("Low", "Medium", "High"), num_cases, replace=TRUE, prob = c(0.5,0.35,0.25)))
var2 = runif(num_cases * 3, 10, 35)

generated_data <- data.frame(var3, case, var1, var2)

model <- clogit(case ~ 
           var1 +
           pspline(var2, df = 3) +
           strata(var3),
           data = generated_data)

print(model)
summary(model)$coefficients
```

**Result:**

- Adding a comma after `case ~ var1` does not produce the error. The code now prints coefficients, but the coefficients it returns are different to the ones returned when I remove the comma and use `print(model)`.
- The above code fails to converge when `num_cases = 200`.
- Adding the comma after `case ~ var1` produces another warning:

  `Warning message in clogit(case ~ var1, +pspline(var2, df = 3) + strata(var3), data = generated_data): “weights ignored: not possible for the exact method”`

Comment: Would really like to help but cannot offer any advice or attempts at debugging without a [MCVE]

Comment: The error message makes me wonder if var2 is a factor variable. Check with `sapply(df,class)`

Comment: I tried it with datasets that come with R but don't see the error, and my dataset is very big, so not sure how to make the code more reproducible. Any suggestion?

Comment: @IRTFM, var2 is numeric.

Comment: Short of sharing my dataset, please let me know how to improve the question. My question is mainly about why the `model` object can be printed (which shows the coeffients, errors and p values), but not the `coefficients`? Clearly, it has calculated those values already.

Comment: People can only guess. We have no basis for investigating without an example.

Comment: I'm happy to provide an example--- asking for suggestion on how to do that. The minimum size of the dataset on which the model estimates coefficients is hundreds of lines. Do you want me to upload it somewhere?

Comment: Over the years I have downloaded example datasets from a variety of locations. Dropbox, Google Drive are two that seem fairly common. The most efficient method is to use `dput(head(dataset, 200))` to create a text representation but the other method would be to create a csv file plus a couple of lines of code to do the input. If you can create an example using random values after setting a seed then you could just paste the code into your question body.

Comment: I added a reproducible example. There are also some additional details and I added them to the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that an object of class 'clogit' is being passed by inheritance to `summary.cph` which is apparently not designed for it. You can get the coefficients from the `print.clogit` function, which is what is being implicitly called when you ask for the models results:

```
 model
Call:
clogit(case ~ var1 + pspline(var2, df = 3) + strata(var3), data = generated_data)

               coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z     p
var1Low    -0.02063   0.97958  0.23019 -0.090 0.929
var1Medium -0.02171   0.97852  0.23831 -0.091 0.927
ps(var2)3  -0.05886   0.94284  0.40900 -0.144 0.886
ps(var2)4  -0.10752   0.89806  0.60868 -0.177 0.860
ps(var2)5  -0.16100   0.85129  0.65381 -0.246 0.805
ps(var2)6  -0.23156   0.79330  0.63652 -0.364 0.716
ps(var2)7  -0.26708   0.76561  0.61080 -0.437 0.662
ps(var2)8  -0.23270   0.79239  0.59903 -0.388 0.698
ps(var2)9  -0.23075   0.79394  0.59781 -0.386 0.700
ps(var2)10 -0.27852   0.75690  0.60117 -0.463 0.643
ps(var2)11 -0.26878   0.76431  0.64828 -0.415 0.678
ps(var2)12 -0.24330   0.78404  0.84486 -0.288 0.773

Likelihood ratio test=0.92  on 5.04 df, p=0.9702
n= 300, number of events= 200
```

As a bonus you get the LLR test value and a p-value. If you just want the matrix of the sort typically returned by a summary function, then make the obvious mods to the section of code in `print.coxph`:

```
{ coef <- model$coefficients
se <- sqrt(diag(model$var))
if (is.null(coef) | is.null(se)) 
    stop("Input is not valid")
if (is.null(model$naive.var)) {
    tmp <- cbind(coef, exp(coef), se, coef/se, pchisq((coef/se)^2, 
                                                      1, lower.tail = FALSE))
    dimnames(tmp) <- list(names(coef), c("coef", "exp(coef)", 
                                         "se(coef)", "z", "p"))} }
```

And then tmp will be the desired matrix:

```
 tmp
                  coef exp(coef)  se(coef)           z         p
var1Low    -0.02062820 0.9795831 0.2301878 -0.08961464 0.9285935
var1Medium -0.02171186 0.9785221 0.2383051 -0.09110952 0.9274056
ps(var2)3  -0.05886243 0.9428365 0.4089999 -0.14391797 0.8855652
ps(var2)4  -0.10752217 0.8980566 0.6086828 -0.17664728 0.8597855
ps(var2)5  -0.16099704 0.8512946 0.6538079 -0.24624519 0.8054924
ps(var2)6  -0.23155828 0.7932965 0.6365191 -0.36378845 0.7160160
ps(var2)7  -0.26708193 0.7656103 0.6108000 -0.43726573 0.6619186
ps(var2)8  -0.23269795 0.7923929 0.5990301 -0.38845785 0.6976772
ps(var2)9  -0.23074825 0.7939393 0.5978122 -0.38598783 0.6995057
ps(var2)10 -0.27852015 0.7569030 0.6011671 -0.46329903 0.6431500
ps(var2)11 -0.26877900 0.7643121 0.6482824 -0.41460174 0.6784335
ps(var2)12 -0.24329853 0.7840374 0.8448572 -0.28797593 0.7733652
```

I'm not sure a bug report is warranted but if you think otherwise, then Thomas Lumley is the `clogit` author. The help page for `clogit` does not describe a summary method and it appears that the `print.clogit`, with dispatching to `print.coxph` method was being used for the purposes typically assigned to `summary`.

In addition, the coefficients themselves could have been obtained with `model$coef` but that would not have returned the full matrix of coefficients pus ancillary statistical estimates,

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really helpful. I worked around this problem by writing the printed summary to a file, then reading that file as a csv, giving me a matrix like a normal summary() call would give. But now that I know the problem and its cause, I could write a function that fixes this issue.